# Symfony2 test client not firing Xdebug during PHPUnit test in PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, xdebug, phpstorm

I've run into an interesting and frustrating wrinkle in attempting to run some functional tests on a Symfony2 project I inherited.  I'm sending a `POST` request to one of my controller methods via Symfony's [test client](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#working-with-the-test-client).  The debugger works during the test on the test file itself.  I can set a break point, run the test, and the debugger will stop all processing at that point until I step through.

The problem is that the debugger does *not* work in the code that's accessed by the client request, likely because it is a secondary request/session.

Is there a way around this?  I'm using PhpStorm 7.1.3, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the help of [this post](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5516784#5516784) and supplying the Symfony test client with the right URI.